# react - Difference between createMuiTheme and createTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

As the title says. Both accept same kind of `ThemeOptions` object.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#006400"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#ffa500"
    }
  }
});
```

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#006400"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#ffa500"
    }
  }
});
```

Is createMuiTheme() only for applying styles to Mui components, and not my custom components?

If I want to create custom CSS classes, should I use `makeStyles()` instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`createTheme` is the newer name, `createMuiTheme` is deprecated https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/pull/1885. You are correct `createTheme()` is used to apply different default styles to the Mui components

`makeStyles()` is a good way to make custom css classes for your new components or the Mui components.